# Costume data set datatable

Tags: php, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

**I have json from url like this**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"01",
         "name":"Some.one"
      },
      {
         "id":"02",
         "name":"Some.two"
      }
   ]
}
```

**How to add costume data to show at datatabale ?**

```
| id | name      |     web       |
| 01 | Some.one  | Someone.com   |
| 02 | Some.two  | Sometwo.com   |
```

In this case I want to add one more table where the contents are the data from the name column plus ".com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns: [
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "name" },
    { data: 'name', render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        var html = data.replace(".", "")
        return html+'.com'.toLowerCase() 
    }},
],
```

Explanation
We can retrieve data from json in the same way as above, then create a function in it where we separate the json data, then we add a string (in this case ".com") to the json data that we have separated into the function